# JSONObject.toString Type mismatch cannot convert from JSONString to JSONObject

Tags: java, json

Per the API we should be able to do this.

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#toString()

```
  @Override
  public JSONObject buildPayload(BuildData buildData, String jenkinsUrl, List<String> logLines) {
    JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
    payload.put("data", buildData.toJson());
    payload.put("message", logLines);
    payload.put("source", "jenkins");
    payload.put("source_host", jenkinsUrl);
    payload.put("@timestamp", buildData.getTimestamp());
    payload.put("@version", 1);

    // we need to flatten payload from JSONObject to String
    return payload.toString();
  }
```

Clearly, we have defined payload and it is a JSONObject. Why isn't this working and what should be done?

Comment: What failure are you exactly facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method declares that it returns a value of type `JSONObject`. But this:

```
return payload.toString();
```

returns a value of type `String`. There's no implicit conversion from `String` to `JSONObject`, hence the compile-time error.

If you really want a string, change the method return type. If you really want a `JSONObject`, just change the return statement to:

```
return payload;
```